# Tabulator JS - how to validate numeric fields while user is typing

Tags: javascript, validation, cell, tabulator

My goal is to have a numeric field that validates as the user types, but it seems that validation only runs after the user leaves the cell.
Is it is possible to start cell validation when the user types, and continue refresh it again as the user continues to type or edit the field.
In the example below from v4.9 examples I have edited a numeric field and then left the cell once, which correctly gives an error.
But if I renter the cell and correct it to a positive number without letters, it will still show the red validation border while editing until I leave the cell.
[image]

1. What I would like is to have the validation re-run on each character
   edit, so the border color will then update as you edit, and the user will know the value can be accepted before leaving the cell.
2. I would also like
   to prevent any entry into the cell other than a decimal
   number (ie. only one decimal point and only numeric characters so that the letter e can never appear in the cell), but
   have not found the answer yet. The numeric format appears to be for
   integers and shows step arrows at end, so not suitable for numbers with 1 or 2 decimal places.

Can anyone point me in the right directions?

Answer (score 0):

Do a [Custom Editor](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/edit#edit-custom) that validates on each keypress

Comment: That was what I started doing but the validator function only occurs when submitted or leaving the cell, not on per key edit.I have not found a way of calling it on each key press .

Comment: On restricting to numbers, I found that you can set the input type to number and you get up and down arrows which is standard html input box so only numbers go in in.  With a bit more research I find there is a css syntax for ::webkit that you can use to hide the arrow keys and there is a step property that can be set to 0.01 to allow 2 decimal places.  So numbers field are now sorted without a needing a custom validator.